# Drools Expert and Workflow: Unable to resolve ObjectType

Tags: workflow, drools

I have these validation rule in Drools Expert which I have tested and works fine:

```
package com.myapp.validationPackage

import com.myapp.model.*;

declare Message 
    type : String 
    text : String 
end

function Message error(String text) { 
    Message message = new Message(); 
    message.setType("ERROR"); 
    message.setText(text);
    return message;
}

rule "First Validation"
    ruleflow-group "Entity Validation"
    when
        Entity( $h : history )
        not ( exists EntityHistory(closeDate == null) from $h
            ) 
    then
        insert( error("Entity must be open") );
end
```

Now I want to use this rule in a workflow but give me this error when I try to build the .rf file on Eclipse:

**Unable to resolve ObjectType 'Message' : [Rule name='RuleFlow-Split-XX'] ..**

How should I use the delcared type to avoid the error?

Thanks.